# PHP How to pass URL parameter into another URL

Tags: php, url, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a URL with a parameter

```
www.url.com/page.php?n=name
```

Now, within a page.php I need to create a hyperlink that works with that parameter. I now have

```
<a href="page2.php?a=param2&n=<?php $_GET["n"] ?>" >
```

but this does not work and the URL shows with empty parameter "n":

```
http://www.url.com/page2.php?a=param2&n=
```

Could you please help me to pass that parameter in the hyperlink? Kindly thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['n']`? Also, always use `urlencode` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `<?php echo $_GET["n"] ?>`

The echo actually prints it into the code. You were just calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the PHP out so it is echoed out to the HTML, and is then in the source code.

Like so:

```
<a href="page2.php?a=param2&n=<?php echo $_GET["n"] ?>" >
```

Comment: @Hidde Well, yes, but this is not in the scope of the question, and the caveats/pros/cons of `urlencode` would need to be explained. I also see no checking of the variable, and I would suggest setting the `$_GET` var to another var too, but again, the OP has a simple problem so is probs a long way from using such things.

Comment: Still, I would always give advice so that people start thinking about security risks, and this code doesn't end up in an end-user web-application.